# How can I use a declared variable as the target of INTO?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The @BACKUP_TABLE_NAME variable can be used when querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.

But, I want to use the fully qualified @FQP_BACKUP_TABLE variable as the target of the INTO clause.

How can I use a variable on the INTO clause?

```
USE THE_DATABASE;

-- Real table = 'THE_TABLE'
-- Backup table = 'BACKUP_TABLE'

DECLARE @BACKUP_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(64) = 'BACKUP_TABLE';
DECLARE @FQP_BACKUP_TABLE VARCHAR(128) = 'THE_BACKUP_DATABASE.dbo.' + @BACKUP_TABLE_NAME

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM THE_BACKUP_DATABASE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = @BACKUP_TABLE_NAME)
BEGIN
    -- Backup table already exists. Do not overwrite it.
    PRINT 'ERROR: Backup table ' + @BACKUP_TABLE_NAME + ' already exists.'
    RAISERROR('ERROR: Cannot overwrite existing backup table.', 18, -1)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- Backup table does not exist. Create it.
    SELECT *
    INTO THE_BACKUP_DATABASE.dbo.BACKUP_TABLE
    --INTO @FQP_BACKUP_TABLE    -- NEVER WORKS
    FROM THE_DATABASE.dbo.THE_TABLE;
END;
```

Comment: SQL Server does not support macro substitution.  You would have to use Dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, `@BACKUP_TABLE_NAME` appears to be working in the test of INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES. Is that considered "Dynamic SQL?"

Comment: To answer your question ... No.   That would be a variable.  See answer below for a Dynamic SQL example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the final insert in a Dynamic SQL statement.

Example

```
...
BEGIN
    Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
    SELECT *
    INTO '+ @FQP_BACKUP_TABLE +'
    FROM THE_DATABASE.dbo.THE_TABLE;'

    Exec(@SQL)        
    
END;
```

Comment: Or, use sp_executesql.